# How do I permanently set my cookie preferences?

Tags: support, login, cookies, gdpr

I visit Stack Overflow on my phone several times a week, and it seems like about once a week (maybe more?) I get this cookie banner.

[image]

I make my selections, and expect the site to remember them. A week later, the prompt will show up again, and nag me for my selections over and over again.

This is all from the same browser, same device, same account, etc. I don’t log off or anything. How do I make this site remember my cookie choices for good?

These are my cookie settings, I don’t have “block all cookies” enabled, so I’m not sure what could be causing this.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your browser to make sure it's not automatically clearing site cookies/data at some times? It's possible to have your browser auto-clear such things in many/most browsers under various conditions. Clearing that information would definitely cause this sort of problem.

Comment: As of the looks of your screenshot, it has something to do with the safari settings that you have set.

Comment: If you're using the extension DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials then it imposes a maximum of 7 day expiration limit  on [first party cookies](https://help.duckduckgo.com/privacy/web-tracking-protections/#1st-party-cookie-protection). Such a cookie holds the consent details and is normally set to expire after a year but with DDG PE it expires in a week. Unfortunately, I don't think you can disable just this behaviour. You can either turn protection off for a site (extension still works everywhere else) or disable the extension everywhere.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue on Firefox and Brave, that too multiple times a day. It's super frustrating cause SO is the only site with this issue (not sure about Stack Exchange sites). For context, `Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows` is disabled in both the browsers.

Comment: YES! This problem is new (recent). And I see it only on StackOverflow, not on the other SE site I visit (several times a day). It's as if StackOverflow is treating me like a new user, even though I visit it every day. This is annoying! And no, none of the comments here apply to me; I'm not doing anything special. Brave is my browser. This is an annoying **bug** or **misfeature**, introduced recently. Please fix this - respect and persist the cookie settings a user makes. Users will change their settings when they want to - otherwise, leave them alone. Thx.

Comment: This is *really* annoying. It just happened to me twice in a couple of minutes, browsing to SO from profile links on other SE sites.

Comment: I see no reason why all logins to SE shouldn't also be logins to SO, AskUbuntu and any other site on the SE network and no reason why a "Necessary Cookies Only" preference can't be retained in our user data record. Come on SE !